# Button is unclickable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, button

[Video where you can see that tapping has no result](https://youtube.com/shorts/ihHAEKXc8S8?feature=share)

Also it is important to know that these widgets are inside of a stack created by FlutterMap. (flutter package flutter_map)

So the first time I press the button "trazi ovdje" / Search Region Button everything works the onTap function of my elevated button is being called. If I press the marker,  the carousel item pops up and after the carousel item disappears you can still see the button "trazi ovdje" / SearchRegionButton but now I can't press it.

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          if (_showSearchRegionButton)
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _slidingAnimation,
              builder: (context, child) {
                print(_resetSearchRegionButton);
                final double calculatedOffset = _slidingAnimation.value.dy * _shopItemHeight;
                print(calculatedOffset);
                return Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(0, !_showCarousel ? 0 : calculatedOffset),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: FadeTransition(
                  opacity: _fadeAnimation,
                  child: buildSearchRegionButton(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (_showCarousel && _currentShops.isNotEmpty) ...[
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            ExpandablePageView.builder(
              controller: _pageController,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: _slidingAnimationDuration),
              // when it will be called with jumpToPage, it will be 0
              // and therefore lead to a weird jump behaviour
              onPageChanged: _onShopItemScrolled,
              itemCount: _currentShops.length,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                final shopItem = ShopItem(
                  shop: _currentShops[index],
                  origin: _mapController.camera.center,
                );

                return SlideTransition(
                  position: _slidingAnimation,
                  child: shopItem,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
          const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ],
      ),
```